# Alter auto-generation of host for routes in openshift on namespace basis

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, gitops

I try to adjust the template for generating routes within a single namespace.
So basically what openshift does, when I enter a route without settng the host via yaml is generate a route in the following way:

`${name}-${namespace}.myapps.mycompany.com`

I would prefer to have a base domain for many routes which differs in the path, e.g.:

`${namespace}.myapps.mycompany.com/${name}`

Is this possible? Especially If I am not an admin of openshift at my company but a dev whose team is responsible just for a few namespaces?

For context: We want to use ArgoCD + Git to use gitops, but do not want to hardcode any infrastructure knowledge like the host or domain in our git repo. We came from using ingresses, but if we omit the host there no routes are generated at all...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can have [path-based routes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-path-based-routes_route-configuration), e.g., `[host]/[path]`. If you don't provide your own value for `[host]`, it will use the same OpenShift `${name}-${namespace}.myapps.mycompany.com` based values.

I'm not sure that you can change OpenShift's default route template, but you can definitely provide your own path values.